# How to use BigQuery's new ASSERT statement with EU located data

Tags: sql, debugging, google-bigquery

The BigQuery release notes for July 13th 2020 announced that the [`ASSERT` statement](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/debugging-statements) is now available.

I was trying it out with my data but couldn't get it to work. Issue seems to be that my data is in EU location, as opposed to US. The release notes and page make no mention of `ASSERT` being region specific so I'm unsure if I'm using it wrong or this is a bug.

To test I created two datasets, `dataset_eu` and `dataset_us`, in the relevant locations. In each I made the same table called `inputs` from the following query:

```
SELECT 'foo' AS x
UNION ALL
SELECT 'bar' AS x
```

Querying the US dataset with a processing location of US runs fine.

```
ASSERT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dataset_us.inputs) > 0 AS 'No rows'
```

However querying the EU dataset with a processing location of EU runs gives an `Unsupported statement ASSERT` error.

```
ASSERT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dataset_eu.inputs) > 0 AS 'No rows'
```

[image: error thrown in EU]

I did also try including project prefix but still got error.

Comment: It seems to be fixed by now Mark!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a bug/limitation on BigQuery side. I'm also facing the same issue while testing this new feature.

I've created a [public issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/161297466) in the IssueTracker.

FTR: This is even easier to reproduce. Execute the following query with different "processing location" in the "query options":

```
    ASSERT TRUE
```

EDIT: Since today, it is working. It seems that Google resolved the issue!